# TextButton and Icon align to left

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:calendar_app/consts/routes.dart';

  class AddTaskView extends StatelessWidget {
      const AddTaskView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 202, 202, 202),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 15,
          vertical: 30,
        ),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                    homePageRoute,
                    (route) => false,
                  );
                },
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back_ios_new,
                  size: 40,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              const Text(
                'Add Task',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 35,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
// Calendar app
```

When I executed this Icon and Text are not aligned to the left.
I want to align the icon like the text widget.
Anyone know how to do it?
Thank you!
Here's a screenshot. [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with `IconButton`'s padding. You can set it default(8) to zero.

```dart
IconButton(
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  onPressed: () {
    
  },
  icon: const Icon(
    Icons.arrow_back_ios_new,
    size: 40,
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `IconButton` padding to `zero` and set it's `alignment` to `centerLeft`. Try this:

```
IconButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,// add this
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,// add this
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                  homePageRoute,
                  (route) => false,
                );
              },
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back_ios_new,
                size: 40,
              ),
            ),
```

[image]